# $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n, G) \cong G[n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I'm doing this exercise:

G is an abelian group, prove that $$\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n, G) \cong G[n]= \lbrace g \in G | ng = 0 \rbrace$$

My attempt: Let's consider the exact sequence $$ 0 \to G[n] \to G \to G$$ where the first arrow is the inclusion and the second is the multiplication by $n$.
We apply the functor $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n, -) $
, which is left exact and obtain the exact sequence $$0 \to \hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n, G[n]) \to \hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n, G) \to 0$$ Thus $$\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n, G) \cong \hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n, G[n])$$

But it's easily seen that $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n, G[n]) \cong G[n]$.

Is my solution correct ? Are there better/ more elegant solutions ?

Comment: Since $n f(x) = f(n \cdot x) = 0$, it's clear that there is a 1:1 mapping bewtween $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n, G)$ and $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n, G[n])$. I think the original statement is as easy to prove as the last statement in your proof. Just follow the suggestion in the answers.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: I thought this solution because the text of the exercise contained a suggestion in this direction, anyway thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any $f\in\hom_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z}_n,G)$, then one can easily check that the map
$$f\mapsto f(1)$$ gives an isomorphism between $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z}_n,G)$ and $G[n]$.